# How to make a 3rd person Controller in Unity 3D continuously run

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a racing game in unity like Temple Run where the player needs to constantly run and collect fruits/ power ups. I am using the 3rd person default construction worker to make this work. But can't figure out what to tweak in the script to make it run continuously.. Help me where exactly I need to change this.

Comment: What do you mean by run continuously? As in, you want to do some logic repeatedly, every X milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should look in this script: `Standard Assets\Character Controllers\Sources\Scripts\CharacterMotor.js`.

The easy part would be to set `var sprint : boolean = false;` to `true` instead.

If you don't need the walking code, you have to clean up some more code in that script to avoid using unnessecary code lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all you need animations.  Then change them to loop and call them run or turn. then for part of the script.

```
function Update ()
{
     animation.Play("run");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at similar [question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/316685/changeing-walk-script-to-always-move.html).